# How to remove focus on button after menu opens up with onFocus event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a menu implemented following Material UI's Menu with an icon. The goal is to allow users to hover with mouse or keyboard tab focus on the 3 dots, not click, to open up the menu. The menu closes when one item is clicked with mouse or enter key.

To achieve that, I have added onFocus and onMouseOver to Menu. It works as expected with the mouse/ hover. The problem is keyboard tab. The focus never leaves the 3 dots icon after the menu opens up. I will need a focus on the menu or first item of menu. How do I resolve this issue? Thanks!

```
      <IconButton
        onFocus={handleClick}
        onMouseOver={handleClick}
      >
        <MoreVertIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id="long-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        {options.map(option => (
          <MenuItem />
        ))}
      </Menu>
```

The complete code sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-y5ikb)

Comment: your codesandbox doesn't match the code you posted in the question

Comment: Having the menu open when the button receives focus is problematic and seems like a bad idea. When the menu closes, focus returns to the button which opens the menu, so it is impossible to close the menu using the keyboard. More standard would be for certain keys (e.g. space, down arrow) to open the menu when focus is on the button.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I was thinking the same. I changed to the open up onClick instead.